# Splitting WordPress theme CSS into multiple files, good or bad?

Tags: theme-development, css, framework

I'm developing a WordPress theme framework. I want organize CSS for each section into separate files for the following reasons.

1. Developers can easily deregister styles by parent theme and load their own styles.
2. Easy to maintain.
3. I can load only the required styles based on the options selected by the user.

Disadvantages
Extra http requests => more load on the server.

This disadvantage can be taken care by combining all the CSS files before they are served to the user using plugins like wp-minify.

But, will this combining process out weigh the above advantages.

Comment: You could still do something like using different files for development and production: `.dev.css` and (compressed, combined) `.css` file extensions.

Comment: Ease of maintenance is not the only reason i want to have separate files.

My framework by default allows users to choose between 9 layouts and 3 navigation styles. All these achieved through CSS keeping HTML constant.

Earlier I used to generate a secondary stylsheet including the required files and store it in ulploads directory, but that has some security  issues.

getting around this security risk is possible, but its complicated and not user friendly. 

I'm hoping combining the individual files wont tax the server.

Answer (score 2):

From http://headjs.com/ :

There is a common misbelief that a single combined script performs best. Wrong:

- latest browsers and Head JS can load scripts in parallel. loading 3 parts in parallel instead of as a single chunk is usually faster.
- iPhone 3.x cannot cache files larger than 15kb and in iPhone 4 the limit is 25kb. And this is the size before gzipping. if you care about iPhones you should respect these limits

(i dont know if it means .css and .js or only .js)

Comment: Google page speed tool recommends to combine multiple js and CSS files?

Loading on the user side isnt the problem.
Multiple connections from the client will put load on the server (correct me if I'm wrong), most of the users of the theme will be on shared hosting with limited resources.

Lets say, I already made the decision to combine the files.

Does combining the files before serving the page have any downsides??

Answer (score 0):

Following @edelwater's excellent answer, another side-effect of the 'combine all' mantra is the induction of unused selectors.

Whilst perhaps unnoticeable on modern desktops, there's still an extra hit on rendering time. For example, [Chrome audit advises their removal](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-V04Coubgp3I/Taq11H7uYrI/AAAAAAAABB4/RYmphnt7NL0/s1600/unused-css.PNG) as part of improving performance.

Of course, loading *every* declaration on-demand is ridiculous (not to mention counter-intuitive). It's down to common sense, plucking out considerable chunks that aren't used for the majority of the site, and loading them in with `wp_enqueue_style()` when they're needed.

**Update:**  Yes, of course there'll be overhead if you're combining your stylesheets on-demand (read: for every request). However, I believe plugins like WP Minify cache the output on first request, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Im not talking about page specific styles.

For example
Once the user picks the layout and navigation styles, CSS specific to the layout and navigation selected has to be loaded.

Comment: Im not talking about page specific styles.

For example
Once the user picks the layout and navigation styles, CSS specific to the layout and navigation selected has to be loaded.

Question is should i combine them and store it in uploads directory, or load those two file seperately and combine them while serving the page to the visitor.

Defnitely the first method is better, but this implementation has problems.

We either have to give the webuser write permissions to those files, which is a security risk.

Comment: We can do it using the method wordpress follows to update plugins and themes, but for that we need ftp login on some installation, and most users are scared hearing ftp.

Also, using ajax on options page might not be possible with this method.

Comment: I understand your point, but felt it was worth mentioning given the title of your post. However, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you edelwater and TheDeadMedic for you answers.

I think I will use the WordPress file system to save the files to uploads directory.

http://ottopress.com/2011/tutorial-using-the-wp_filesystem/

I have to ask for ftp login on some wordpress installs, I think I can handle that without loosing the AJAX options page using page overlay like wordpress uploader.